# How to Include user-defined Header files in your source code in Code::blocks if Your Header file is present in the same directory as your source file?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files

I'm a C++ beginner, i created my own .h file and .cpp file in the same directory as in Source code.  I tried to include the Header file in the source code.  My Header file gets included only if i type

```
#include "../headerfile.h"
```

but it won't accept `#include "headerfile.h"`

i'm using code::blocks.

why is that, is that a Rule (kinda like syntax) or something i'm Mistaken.

EDIT:
Hi, so the Mistake is with me, I didn't include .h file file in the same folder as the Main function, if I included the Source Code + .h in the Same Folder i can just do
`#include "(.hFileName).h"`.

I'm New to Stackoverflow also, I don't whether should i delete this dumb question or Not.  so, I Leave it for the Good editors and People who work Implicitly.

[also thanks to the comment section]

Comment: It depends where the header file lies in relation o the source file and which include directories are specified. Right now the header file is one directory above ( = ".." ) from the source file. If you would include a file from a directory down your source file you would use it with the directory name like `#include "directory/header.h"`

Comment: It might be your project file configured incorrectly.

Comment: How is structured your project directory tree? Have you added your source and headers files to the CodeBlocks project?